# MEDIANIFS() in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, median, vba

I'm teaching myself VBA at the moment, & one thing that's really bugged me is that Excel doesn't have  MEDIANIFS() function. My research has found:

- A MEDIANIF (one condition, not multiple) formula in VBA
- The array formula for {MEDIAN(IF(...))}
- Putting medians into pivot tables

PS. This is *not* self study, so posting a solution is fine, but tips are also welcome

Edited version:

My question is, given that I have a MEDIANIF() formula programmed in VBA, how can I modify it to take more than one condition? To turn it into a MEDIANIFS()

```
> Function MedianIf(rng As Range, Criteria As Variant) As Variant
>     Dim cell As Range
>     Dim ar() As Variant
>     Dim i    As Long
>     
>     With WorksheetFunction
>         If .CountIf(rng, Criteria) = 0 Then
>             MedianIf = CVErr(2036) '-- #NUM!
>         Else
>             ReDim ar(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
>             For Each cell In rng.Cells
>                 If .CountIf(cell, Criteria) = 1 Then
>                     i = i + 1
>                     ar(i) = cell.Value
>                 End If
>             Next
>             MedianIf = .Median(ar)
>         End If
>     End With End Function
```

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?650584-RESOLVED-Writing-MedianIf-in-VBA

Comment: What is your question? You told us that you found 3 solutions, why do none of them work for you?

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman. These solutions are good, but I want to build an add-in for my colleagues to use them. I'm not sure that the other solutions would be easy enough for my users to implement (array formula too complicated, pivot too fiddly)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *parameter array* to be able to include multiple criteria. To give you an idea of the mechanics:

```
Sub MultiCriteria(target As Range, ParamArray Criteria() As Variant)
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim criterion As Variant
    s = target.Address & " to be filtered by:"
    For i = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
        criterion = Criteria(i)
        s = s & vbCrLf & "Criterion " & i & ": " & criterion
    Next i
    Debug.Print s
End Sub

Sub test()
    MultiCriteria Range("A1:B10"), "<5", "<>6", "=C5"
End Sub
```

Output of test:

```
$A$1:$B$10 to be filtered by:
Criterion 0: <5
Criterion 1: <>6
Criterion 2: =C5
```

You could possibly use AND() to gather the criteria into 1, or you can apply the criteria in a loop. I don't have time to develop a complete implementation of MEDIANIF right now but this should get you started. Ask another question if you run into more difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a generic array function FUNCTION_IF_SET():

```
Function FUNCTION_IF_SET(functionName As String, _
                         rang As Range, _
              ParamArray rangesAndcriteria() As Variant) As Variant
'Use: _
  FUNCTION_IF_SET "MEDIAN", _
                   rang, _
                   ranges Criterion1, criteria1, _
                   rangesCriterion2, criteria2
Dim cel As Range
Dim auxRange Range As Range
Dim conditionRange Range As Range
Dim cond As String
Dim include As Boolean
Dim arrParam() As Variant
Dim arrCond() As String
Dim rc As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim jj As Integer

On Error Resume Next

If Not IsMissing(rangesAndcriteria) Then
   'If the criteria parameter is a single parameter (array)
    If LBound(rangesAndcriteria) = UBound(rangesAndcriteria) Then
       arrParam = rangesAndcriteria(UBound(rangesAndcriteria))
    else
        arrParam = rangesAndcriteria
    End If
    For i = 1 To rang.Cells.Count
        jj = -1
        include = True
        For rc = LBound(arrParam) To UBound(arrParam) Step 2
            Set conditionRange = arrParam(rc)(i)
            cond = arrParam(rc + 1)
            If cond = nStr Then 'empty cell
               If conditionRange <> nStr Then
                   include = False
                   Exit For
               End If
            ElseIf cond = "<>" Then 'non-empty cell
                   If conditionRange = nStr Then
                       include = False
                       Exit For
                   End If
            ElseIf cond Like "=*" Then
                   cond = VBA.Mid(cond , 2)
                   If Not cond Like "~*" And _
                      Not cond Like "~?" then
                      If conditionRange <> cond Then
                          include = False
                          Exit For
                      End If
                   ElseIf Not conditionRange  Like cond Then
                          include = False
                          Exit For
                   End If
            ElseIf cond  Like "<>*" Then
                   cond = VBA.Mid(cond , 3)
                   If Not cond Like "~*" And _
                      Not cond Like "~?" then
                      If conditionRange = cond Then
                          include = False
                          Exit For
                      End If
                   ElseIf conditionRange Like cond Then
                          include = False
                          Exit For
                   else
                       include = False
                       Exit For
                   End If
            ElseIf cond Like "*,*" Then
                   arrCond = VBA.Split(cond , ",")
                   include = False
                   For j = LBound(arrCond) To UBound(arrCond)
                       If conditionRange = arrCond(j) And _
                         (j = jj Or jj = -1) Then
                          If jj = -1 Then jj = j
                          include = True
                          Exit For
                       End If
                   Next
                   If Not Include Then Exit For
            ElseIf conditionRange <> cond Then
                   include = False
                   Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If include Then
           If auxRange Is Nothing Then
              Set auxRange = range(i)
           else
               Set auxRange = Union(auxRange, range(i))
           End If
        End If
    Next
else
     set auxRange = range
End If

Select Case functionName
        Case "MEDIAN"
             FUNCTION_IF_SET = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(auxRange)
        Case "Other"
             FUNCTION_IF_SET = Application.WorksheetFunction...(auxRange)
End Select

End Function 'FUNCTION_IF_SET
```

NOTE: there may be some error due to the translation.